# Not able to access microsoft teams toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-code, teams-toolkit

I am trying to create new teams app using Microsoft teams toolkit inside visual studio code.

I have installed Microsoft teams toolkit extension. When I am trying to create a new app all the options are disabled and show the clock symbol on teams extension. Please help me out to resolve this issue.
I am attaching image link here[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CosHK.png)
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension takes some time (usually several seconds) to activate which depends on the machine state. If this is your first installation, the time cost is larger. From the attached image, it seems that the Teams Toolkit extension is still activating so that it has a running progress bar on the top of sidebar. During this time, the buttons are disabled. After that, the buttons will be enabled.